# How do I get rid of a keylogger?

Tags: security, anti-malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I recently lost my access to my online gaming account. I had to report to customer service and they asked me to check that there aren't any keyloggers installed on my computer (to make sure nobody is stealing my account password).

How do I determine if I have a keylogger installed and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Get an anti-malware (anti-virus) program.

Comment: I've got it, but it makes my computer performance down to play the game, is not there another way?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: *> I've got it, but it makes my computer performance down to play the game, is not there another way?*   You can turn off the real-time scanner while playing, but running a manual scan when you are not isn't an issue.

Comment: Maleware makes computer performance go down as well.

Comment: Don't excuse yourself for your English and your poor knowledge every time please.

Comment: @Artium Macho software?

Comment: @ Oliver why are you editing a question that needs to be closed? This question is a general malware infection question that has been answered in a SU wiki. Please vote to close the question instead of editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are already infected, there are few things you can do to detect the virus. Installing or re-enabling the anti-virus will not reveal the virus as it might manipulate the AV software as well.

There are few things that can raise your suspicion though.

First thing is major performance slowdown, especially if you remember that the computer was not as slow and you did not add programs that can slow it down.

Second is what you described. If your personal information is being compromised then it might be a virus on your computer. But remember that it might be other things as well. For example your password for the game was weak or you logged in when connected to a public wireless network or your friend got your password somehow etc.

Third thing is crashes and blue screens. If you experience these a lot, it might be a hardware problem, driver bug, but sometimes it is a virus.

Comment: Oliver why are you editing an answer to a question that needs to be closed? This question is a general malware infection question that has been answered in a SU wiki. Please vote to close the question instead of editing an answer to it....http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now